# How can I make a currently-Pinax project be easier for future developers to work with?

Tags: django, pinax

I'm attempting to install a Pinax-based project that someone else built starting at least a year ago. Their install is based off off 0.7beta3, and I cannot find a tarball for that anywhere on the internet.

I found one on a developer's machine, and it won't install because it's looking for dependencies on pypi.pinaxproject.com, which doesn't have old versions of anything.

Upgrading to 0.7.3 seems to be a project in and of itself. I looked briefly at 0.5.1 because I needed some code from it to upgrade to 0.7.3, and it doesn't look like 0.5.1 is installable at this point. Should I assume, therefore, that when 0.9.x comes out, 0.7.3 won't be installable?

If I keep this project in Pinax and just get it working with 0.7.3, will the next developer who works on this and has to install it from scratch have to do the same with 0.9.x?

If I pull out the apps that this project uses and use them directly, will that make it easier for the next developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling out the apps seems the most viable option, as that also means less dependency on the outdated Pinax code.